# Converting None values with pandas.to_datetime is unpredictable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Why does `pandas` convert `None` values in the different ways for `to_datetime` (unpredictable) and `to_numeric` (predictable)?

```
import pandas as pd

VALUE = None

print(pd.to_datetime(VALUE))
print(pd.to_numeric(VALUE))

print(pd.__version__)
```

returns

```
None
nan
0.23.4
```

Why not `pd.to_datetime(None) is pd.NaT`?

Comment: What do you see for `VALUE = [None]` ?

Comment: ``pd.to_datetime([None])`` returns ``DatetimeIndex(['NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)``, but ``pd.to_numeric([None])`` returns ``array([nan])`` (still predictable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is [`pd.to_datetime`](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L106-L471) in `datetimes.py` includes:

```
if arg is None: 
    return None
```

*Why* this design choice was taken is a question better directed to the Pandas developers, e.g. you may wish to [raise a github issue](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue/).

As you found, treatment with a list or series, i.e. the *usual* use case, is consistent:

```
VALUE = [None]

pd.to_datetime(VALUE)  # DatetimeIndex(['NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
pd.to_numeric(VALUE)   # [ nan]
```

As a workaround, for scalars I suggest you use [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
pd.Timestamp(None)     # NaT
```

Comment: I should use ``lambda x: pd.NaT if x is None else pd.to_datetime(x, errors="coerce")`` in my case (the function is the element of converters dictionary)